# The Chinese word can't show correctly when I decode the base64url string

Tags: url, base64, gmail-api

I already get the message.raw using gmail api. But when I try decode the string, I get the right English words while Chinese word is not show correctly.Is anything wrong with my decode code

```
    /// <summary>
    /// decode raw字符串
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="base64ForUrlInput"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] FromBase64ForUrlString(string base64ForUrlInput)
    {
        int padChars = (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4) == 0 ? 0 : (4 - (base64ForUrlInput.Length % 4));
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(base64ForUrlInput, base64ForUrlInput.Length + padChars);
        result.Append(String.Empty.PadRight(padChars, '='));
        result.Replace('-', '+');
        result.Replace('_', '/');
        return Convert.FromBase64String(result.ToString());
    }
```

`

Comment: I suspect the problem lies less with the Base64 decoding and more with the `byte[]`-to-string decoding.

Comment: the code about byte[] to String :string result = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msgbytes);

Comment: Is that right ?  I tried different encode including utf-8 ,ascII and unicode. but the result is all the same

Comment: You’ll need to look at the message headers to figure out what encoding it is, but just as a guess it could be [GB 18030](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB_18030).

Comment: I got this, thank you!